# AVPlayerViewController not showing up

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having trouble with the AVPlayerViewController right now. I have a table view with a bunch of videos and I want to play the video after selecting the table view cell. However, the video(AVPlayerViewController) is not showing up, **but the sound of the video is playing so I think the video is successfully opened, just not showing up.** I am using the         self.window?.rootViewController?.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) method, is it still working in contemporary version? My tutorial told me to use self.present but I get an error saying "Value of type 'VideoPostCell' has no member 'present'". Any idea of what is going on. Any help is appreciated. (I cut part of the code to make it simpler)

**Table view cell code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class VideoPostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
    
    
    static let identifier: String = "VideoPostCell"
    
    static func nib() -> UINib{
        return UINib(nibName: "VideoPostCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    var playURL: URL? //Don't worry about it, it will be passed in
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if let safeURL = playURL{
            playVideo(videoURL: safeURL)
        }else{
            return
        }
    }
    
    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()

    func playVideo(videoURL: URL){
        print("selected")
        
        playerView = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        playerViewController.player = playerView
        
        
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Put something else in the cell and see whether that shows up.

Comment: What is your rootViewController at that moment? Will it be possible that it is already presenting other view controllers?